# opção em branco @htm.EnumDropDownListFor MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-helper

Estou com um problema no meu razor, quero que a opção que venha selecionado seja uma em branco. meu razor é assim:

```
 @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Endereco.Zona, string.Empty ,new { @class = "form-control-sm", style = "height: 20px;padding: 0;width: 156px" })
```

eu tentei assim também:

```
 @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Endereco.Zona,"Selecione" ,new { @class = "form-control-sm", style = "height: 20px;padding: 0;width: 156px" })
```

mas de toda forma, vem selecionado sempre a opção 0. o HTML que gera fica dessa maneira:

```
     <select class="form-control-sm valid">
   <option value=""></option>
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Norte</option>
    <option value="1">Sul</option>
    <option value="2">Sudeste</option>
    <option value="3">Nordeste</option>
    <option value="4">CentroOeste</option>
    </select>
```

Percebi que um option vem com uma opção selected:

```
<option selected="selected" value="0">Norte</option>
```

Alguém sabe como eu posso fazer para mudar isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta alterar o tipo do seu **enum Zona** em um enum anulável, da seguinte forma:

> public Zona? Zona { get; set; }

Isso também permite que você use o Required no atributo, que acho que é significativamente mais limpo. O Required no atributo não permitirá uma resposta nula, portanto, mesmo que seu modelo permita nulos, o formulário não.

Comment: perfeito amigo... muito obrigado... uma coisinha de nada, me fez bater cabeça ora caramba!!!

Comment: Que bom que deu certo, acontece, já passei por isso também.